# Pushing to a bare repository on shared hosting

Tags: git, server, host, sourcetree

I am trying to set up a git repository on a shared hosting server.

My problem is that after I succesfully created a bare repository on the server and cloned it locally, on my computer, every time I try to add changes -> commit -> push them to the remote branch, only the commit part works.

The push is executed succesfully as well, but no changes seem to be done on the server as well.

```
mkdir sitrep
cd sitrep
git --bare init
```

This is how I created the repository on the server

```
git clone ssh://catlipp1@173.254.28.90/home2/catlipp1/public_html/src-crs/sitrep.git
Cloning into 'sitrep'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

And this is how I cloned it. Now I created a file named index.html and used git add index.html to add the changes and then commit.

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 217 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
* [new branch]      master -> master
```

And this is what I get when I try to git push.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Any news to the problem? Did the answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output looks like the `push` command did what it should.

Try to checkout in a second folder. I'm pretty sure that your index.html is present, you only don't see it in your `--bare` repository.

Bare repositories are like `.git` folders in a non-bare one. They contain something like a database for your source files. The files itself are not directly visible in there, the information is stored in database files.

Comment: Thank you for your respose. I tried adding a new file in the same way because there were too many index.html files on the server to look for.

    find -name "my_new_file.html"
    find: `./BackupNow/.system': Permission denied

and this is what I get. The file seems to be on the server indeed (at least it seems like it could find something), but as you can probably see, it's stuck somewere I can't get to it.

Comment: Do you search in your `--bare` repository or in the checked-out version? As I tried to explain, you won't find the file name in the `--bare` repository, only in checked-out versions. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the answer. For those interested, I realized it was just a conceptual misunderstanding. The files are in fact uploaded on the server, they are just not supposed to be shown inside the bare repository, as it's not supposed to have a working copy.

If you do want a working copy on the remote, you can just git clone the bare repository and it will create a repository with a working copy

Comment: Hm, is this any different from my answer?

Comment: Hi! No, the answer is the same. I was just thinking that the bare repository does have a working copy as well, so it was a misunderstanding. I posted my solution so that other beginners can see how they can actually get a working copy on the server. Thanks!